# How to create folder in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, inno-download-plugin

How can i create folder in code section?
I use example script of inno download.

```
[Code]
//HERE I NEED TO CREATE FOLDER "Downloaded"

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
 itd_init;
 itd_addfile('http://link.net/soft/file.exe',expandconstant('{sd}\Downloaded\file.exe'));
 itd_downloadafter(wpReady);
end;
```

Comment: Call [`CreateDir`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createdir) function, or [`ForceDirectories`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_forcedirectories) depending how do you want to create that folder.

Comment: im fu***g newbie in pascal and inno. give an example pls.

Comment: Here is a [`fu***g example`](http://pastebin.com/gsAr23LA) :-)

Comment: oh. i understand:) thx. found it here http://pastebin.com/m78f224bc

Comment: You're welcome! Anyway, the example you linked to is quite unsafe, because in certain circumstances, the folder might not be created. Better use check (like I did in my example), if the craetion succeed and only then start to download what you need.

Comment: The `ForceDirectories` function saved my day!!! Thanks!

Comment: you guys are hilarious!

Answer (score 5):

Why not use the `[Dirs]` section to create a folder:

```
Name: {app}\Downloaded
```